# SVM Result Meaning in R

Tags: r, svm, e1071

I'm new to using the e1071 package for SVM classification in R. I am getting the results below.

```
Parameters:
     SVM-Type: nu-classification 
   SVM-Kernel: sigmoid 
        gamma: 0.03225806 
       coef.0: 0 
           nu: 0.5 

Number of Support Vectors:  229

Parameters:
   SVM-Type:  nu-classification 
 SVM-Kernel:  polynomial 
     degree:  3 
      gamma:  0.03225806 
     coef.0:  0 
         nu:  0.5 

Number of Support Vectors:  235
```

what does gamma, coef.0, nu and degree means?

Comment: Asking for meaning of results is not a coding question. More of a theory question.

Answer (score 1):

- Gamma and coef.0 are parameters in the kernels.

A sigmoid kernel is tanh(gamma*u'*v + coef0).

Degree is used with a polynomial kernel and indicates the degree of the polynomial. A polynomial kernel is (gamma*u'*v + coef0)^degree.

- nu is a parameter needed for nu-classification.